# Insert into Parent and Child table From another table Mysql

Tags: c#, mysql

I have 4 table they are tbl_A, tbl_A_detail (has A_id), tbl_B, tbl_B_detail (has B_id) and I already made a "function" that return a GenerateCode

I want to insert into tbl_A and the values are from tbl_B but with new ID. 
So it will be like this :

> tbl_B #1 row (GX-110, 'Rony')
>
> tbl_B_detail (#1) #1 row (GXD-421, 'jacket', GX-110)
>
> tbl_B_detail (#1) #2 row (GXD-421, 'Hat', GX-110)
>
> tbl_B #2 row (GX-111, 'Joseph')
>
> tbl_B_detail (#2) #1 row (GXD-512, 'Sun Glasses', GX-111)
>
> tbl_B_detail (#2) #2 row (GXD-3623, 'Tissue', GX-111)

i want to move those record to tbl_A (same structure) but with new generate_id FOR tbl_A

then i want to insert into tbl_A_detail from tbl_B_detail with new generate_id FOR tbl_A

`INSERT INTO tbl_A (A_id, a_name, ...) SELECT (SELECT (Generate Code Here)), b.name FROM tbl_b`

`insert into tbl_A_detail(A_detail_id, A_detail_name, A_parent_id) SELECT (SELECT GenerateCode()), B_detail_name, (GeneratedCode FROM inserted Record) FROM tbl_B_detail`

How can i do that? #i am sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0):

your table should support transaction, InnoDB for example.

```
SET autocommit=0;
begin;
set @generated_id=(Generate Code Here);
insert into table_a (id,title) select @generated_id,  title from table_b where id=4;
insert into table_a_detail (id,detail) select @generated_id,  detail from table_b_detail where id=4;
commit;
```

Comment: But Sir i want to move all the record from tbl_B, tbl_B_detail into tbl_A, tbl_A_detail (not just 1 record). i tried your code, but i got an error message " duplicate entry for key primary ". do you have any suggestion?

Comment: You should check if the generated id exists in table_a before it can be use.

Comment: try this:      `SET autocommit=0;
begin;
repeat
    set @generated_id=(Generate Code Here);
    select count(*) into @id_count from table_a where id=@generated_id;
 until @id_count =0;
end repeat;
insert into table_a (id,title) select @generated_id,  title from table_b where id=4;
insert into table_a_detail (id,detail) select @generated_id,  detail from table_b_detail where id=4;
commit; `